# Tomcat 6.0 starts but ecplise thinks it is not

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I am using tomcat 6 with Eclipse Kepler Release.
When i start the tomcat, I see below messages:

> ```
> Aug 03, 2013 11:30:01 AM com.isc.org.apache.coyote.http11.ISCHttp11Protocol start
> INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-444
> Aug 03, 2013 11:30:01 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
> INFO: Server startup in 20742 ms
> ```

This shows that the Tomcat starts but eclipse thinks that the tomcat is not starting yet and keeps showing the starting bar.

When I see the "Progress" window it says:

> Starting tomcat 6.0 Server at Localhost

Do you know why Eclipse think tomcat is not starting while it is started and "working".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the Eclipse calls the application url after start up to make sure it is running.

A proxy client (pshione) had changed the system proxy so the eclipse could not call the start page and thinks that the application is not starting yet!!

I removed the proxy and it works fine now!